# Http subscribe data not assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I want to fetch data from api and assign it to my variable.

In subscribe I assigned data to variable in `subscribe` and console logged variable. Everything okay, variable has now data, but after `subscribe` ends busDepotLocality will still be undefined. Tried to put timeout to await, but nothing

app.component.ts:

```
 busDepotLocality: BusDepotLocality;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.mapService
         .getBusDepotLocality()
         .subscribe((data: BusDepotLocality) => { 
           this.busDepotLocality = data;
           console.log(data); // Data is showing, no problem
           console.log(this.busDepotLocality); //Assignment passed, data is showing, no problem
         });

     console.log(this.busDepotLocality); // But after all busDepotLocality will be undefined
```

Comment: This is because you are mixing sync and async calls. What the subscribe does is that is just setsup a listener, that as soon as the getBusDepotLocality emits a value, it executes what's inside the subscribe. Right after setting up that listener you console log in that last line is executed and since no value has been emitted yet that value is still not set.

Comment: Your variable assignation is in the subscribe scope. Code inside subscribe will be executed once the observable emits a value (i.e. your service returns a response). You first reach the last `console.log()` then you receive a response later and execute the subscribe scope code. To understand the `async` mechanism in javascript, you should have a look at [Philip Roberts wonderful expanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
async ngOnInit() {  // Step 1
   await this.mapService  // Step 2
         .getBusDepotLocality()
         .toPromise().then((data: BusDepotLocality) => { 
           this.busDepotLocality = data; // Step 3
           console.log(data); // Data is showing, no problem
           console.log(this.busDepotLocality); //Assignment passed, data is showing, no problem
         });

   console.log(this.busDepotLocality);  // Step 4
}
```

To Clarify on how we can have async-await in lifecycle hook, here are the steps :

1) In Step 1 we are making the hook async, thus it will not hamper/impact this lifecycle hook as we are not awaiting for this method call at step 1, and it will continue executing other cycle events

2) In Step 2, we are awaiting till we get the response and any lines of code following await, will wait till we get the response of async call ( "http" call )

3) In Step 3, we get the response.

4) In Step 4, we execute rest of the statements.

PS : Since here we are asking to execute statements once everything is complete and you get final response, you need to convert it to promise.

And, if you insist on considering observable you can use async pipe in html

```
\\ Component
  private data:Observable<any>;

 ngOnInit(){
    this.data=this.mapService.getBusDepotLocality();
  }

\\ HTML 

{{data|async}}
```

Else, you can pipe(tap()) your response

Comment: just try once.. also let me clarify in my edit answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log something that is not populated yet.

as proof of this, try

```
busDepotLocality: BusDepotLocality;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.mapService
         .getBusDepotLocality()
         .subscribe((data: BusDepotLocality) => { 
           this.busDepotLocality = data;
           console.log(data); // Data is showing, no problem
           console.log(this.busDepotLocality); //Assignment passed, data is showing, no problem
         },(error) => {console.log(error)},() => {console.log(this.busDepotLocality); });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the problem you are having, you need to have a better understanding of subscriptions. In the easiest way I can think of right now, think about a subscription like it is a *live stream*, which means as long as you are steaming the content you will have access to the data. Now let's apply this concept to the problem you are having, we have the following code:

```
busDepotLocality: BusDepotLocality;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.mapService
         .getBusDepotLocality()
         .subscribe((data: BusDepotLocality) => { 
           this.busDepotLocality = data;
           console.log(data); // Data is showing, no problem
           console.log(this.busDepotLocality); //Assignment passed, data is showing, no problem
         });

     console.log(this.busDepotLocality); // But after all busDepotLocality will be undefined
```

You actually indicate my point with your comment - within the subscription the data is accessible, outside of the subscription, the data cannot be assigned. You would want to map the data then subscribe to the variable whenever you want to access the data. for example:

```
busDepotLocality: BusDepotLocality;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.busDepotLocality = this.mapService
         .getBusDepotLocality()
         .pipe(map((data) => data));
     const results = this.busDepotLocality.subscribe(val => 
         console.log(val)
         //code goes here
     ); 
 }
```